# A generic way of extending service implementations in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

When you want to take advantage of `ISomeService`'s default implementation's capabilities and add custom logic, the most popular way is inheriting from the default implementation class like this:

```
public class CustomService : DefaultService
{
    public override Something ProvideSomething(SomeOptions options) =>
        someCondition ? customSomething : base.ProvideSomething(options);
}
```

Unfortunately, it is problematic with some classes as they don't make all methods I would like to override virtual.

It would be nice to implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern like this:

```
public class CustomService : ISomeService
{
    private ISomeService _next;

    public CustomService(ISomeService next) => _next = next;

    public Something ProvideSomething(SomeOptions options) =>
        someCondition ? customSomething : _next.ProvideSomething(options);
}
```

However, with the default ASP.NET Core DI container it is troublesome to simultaneously register a new version of the service and get the old one. The only way I can think of is to build a temporary IServiceProvider to query it for services before adding new versions.

Does there exist a better approach?

Comment: It may be good idea to show code using some other DI container that supports your needs (I'm not sure how one would express "register a new version of the service and get the old one" concept... indeed there are child containers and interception that somewhat related, but different)

Comment: "Chain of Responsibility pattern like this:". This is not chain of responsibility, but the Decorator design pattern. And yes, the default DI container does not allow you to register decorators. All common DI containers (Simple Injector, Autofac, Ninject, Castle Windsor, Unity, StructureMap) do actually support Decorator, so you might want to switch to one of those. So the better approach is: use a different DI Container.